# C++ finding sum of numbers till the end of user input

Tags: c++

I have to calculate the sum of all numbers that end in either 3, 5 or 7 and output it in main(). I've done that but with the input file being:

`5
35
2
3
28
16
17`

I get `535030017` as output. It just doesn't sum them up but it cout's them. Here is my C++:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumNumbers(int number){
    int sum = 0;

        if (number%10==3||number%10==5||number%10==7){
            sum += number;
        }

    cout << sum;
}

int main ()
{
    int x;
    while(cin >> x){
        sumNumbers(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are resetting the sum to 0 on each call to sumNumbers. Either have a global variable (not encouraged) to maintain the sum or pass the accumulated total as another parameter into sumNumbers (much better) and then print out total in your main function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should fix your issue:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void sumNumbers(int& sum, int number)
{
    if (number%10==3||number%10==5||number%10==7)
    {
       sum += number;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}

int main ()
{
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    while(cin >> x)
    {
       sumNumbers(sum, x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need it to output only 60 in the case that I've shown. And now it returns: `5
40
40
43
43
43
60`

Comment: Of course. How should the programm know when the sum is finished? If you want to print the final sum only you need to move the "cout" line below the loop and you need to exit the loop if input is finished.

Comment: It works with the example in the OP but what if my if loop is like this `if (number%2==0||number%3!=0)` to find if the number is divisible by 2 and NOT divisible by 3?

Comment: What has the divisor to do with this? To break the loop you need to decide how the input can be finished. Should it be finished after entering 7 numbers? Should it be finished if the user enters 0 or -1? Should it be finished if users presses <Enter> without typing a number?

Answer (score 1):

If you need sum then you should do like this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumNumbers(int sum, int number){


    if (number%10==3||number%10==5||number%10==7){
        sum += number;
    }
    cout << sum;
    return sum;
}

int main ()
{
   int sum = 0;
   int x;
   while(cin >> x){
       sum = sumNumbers(sum, x);
   }
}
```

Comment: your sum numbers is declared void

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumNumbers(int sum, int number){
    if (number%10==3||number%10==5||number%10==7){
        sum += number;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main ()
{
 int x, sum=0;
 while (cin >> x){
    sum = sumNumbers(sum, x);
 }
 cout<<"Sum of the numbers ending with 3,5 and 7 is "<<sum;
}
```

And i would suggest you to put a limit on the input by the user otherwise the program will keep on running till user manually breaks it.

This will work finally only when the loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sum` is a new variable for each invocation of `sumNumbers`, so you start over at zero every time.

A slightly different approach, separating filtering, summing , and output:

```
int filterNumber(int number)
{
   int ones = number % 10;
   if (ones == 3 || ones == 5 || ones == 7)
   {
      return number;
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
}

int main()
{
   int sum = 0;
   int x = 0;
   while(cin >> x){
      sum += filterNumber(x);
   }
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```